# Derivation of 2nd order damped rise time

Tags: control-engineering

Given the transfer function: $$\frac{\omega_0}{s^2 + 2\omega_0\zeta s + \omega_0^2}$$

How would you derive the rise time of the system from 0% SS to 100% SS.

$$t_r = \frac{\pi - \arccos{\frac{1}{\zeta}}}{\omega_0 \sqrt{1 - \zeta^2}}$$

I attempted to obtain this by using the solution to the 2nd order ODE: $$y(t) = A \exp{(-\omega_0\zeta t)} \cos{(\omega_0 \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}t)}$$ from $\dot{y}(0) = 0$, $y(0) = -A$ and, $y(t_r) = 0$, where $A$ is the steady state value, however, the solution is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise now that the solution was wrongly assumed, using the BCs you would get $$y(t) = -A  \exp{(-\omega_0\zeta t)}( \cos{(\omega_0 \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}t)} + \frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{ 1-\zeta^2 } }\sin{(\omega_0 \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}t)}) $$

Leading to

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}{\zeta} + \tan{\omega_0 \sqrt{1-\zeta^2} t_r} = 0$$

where $ \arctan{\frac{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}{\zeta}} \equiv \arccos{\frac{1}{\zeta}}$

Then $$\omega_0 \sqrt{1 - \zeta^2} t_r = \pi -\ arctan{ \frac{\sqrt{1 - \zeta^2}}{\zeta} }$$ and the rest is trivial.